# problems with cloudflare's SSL certificate in ubuntu apache2 server

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu, web

I use cloudflare services for DNS and SSL certificate, but even after the certificate config the website ([www.endeavor.tec.br](http://www.endeavor.tec.br)) remains unsafe.

I configured the certified in the serve this way:

1 - I created a certificate(pem) and a key(crt) in the cloudflare.

2 - I enabled the SSL by the following command:

> sudo a2enmod ssl

3 - I created a directory in the origin server and attached both with the names endeavor.tec.br.pem and endeavor.tec.br.crt

4 - I altered the endeavor.tec.br.conf file in the apache directory changing the VirtualHost to the 443 port and inserting SSL lines as follow:

> SSLCertificateFile      /etc/cloudflare/endeavor.tec.br.crt
> SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/cloudflare/endeavor.tec.br.key
> SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/cloudflare/endeavor.tec.br.crt

The website is accessible so the DNS is working, but remains unsafe. How could I fix it?

Comment: How do you know that the website is unsafe? What specific problems are you aware of?

Comment: The browser indicts the Connection is not secure, because there is no SSL certificate for the website. I can only access it by HTTP, but I trying to configure the SSL certificate.

Comment: So, by "secure" you mean support for HTTPS. Have you emptied the cache of CloudFlare?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes, the website doesn't support HTTPS, only access by HTTP and appears not secure for visitors or shows an error (SSL handshake failed) when accessed by Google Chrome. I tryied to empty Cloudflare cache, but it didn't worked also. tks!

Comment: I have resolved this kind of issue in the past, but I'm not an expert in this area, had a lot of difficulty while doing it and now I do not really remember the steps, unfortunately. If I would face the same issue now, then I would probably have an easier time than previously, but I do not know the answer without looking into it, so I cannot help you further. But our discussion is useful, because other people knowing more about these problems might read it and have a more exact idea of what the problem is.